# Error declaring a variable with the declaration statement a method

Tags: java, declaration

I am trying to declare an integer generated at random to a variable ("i") and use that in a if statement. I keep getting errors sating that it doesn't recognize "i" and that "i" wasn't declared. If any one could shed some light on the situation, I would be grateful. This is in an Applet that I am making.

```
    public int tGen()
{
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

    return randomInt;       
}

public int tortoiseMoves()
{
    i = tGen();
    if (i >= 1 && i <= 5)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

The `i = tGen()` is the part I think is wrong and the `System.out.println()` is just a test to see what i is and if the if statement works. And the tGen() method is a generator.

Comment: What is the type of `i`?  Use `int i = tGen();`.

Comment: Well, where did you declare `i`?

Comment: I'll try that. Is it because I was missing a int or a double or whatever?

Comment: `I am trying to declare an integer ` How do you think your code **declares** an integer?

Comment: Ask yourself why did you do `int randomInt`, but only `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `int i = tGen();`.  "int" is the declared type, which must precede the variable name when declaring the variable.  Example:

```
int i = 0; // declare i and initialize it
i = 2; // assign a new value to i
```

Or

```
int i; // declare i; not yet initialized (so it can't be referenced yet)
i = 2; // initialize i
```

Comment: This is also helpful. By the way, why does everyone hate my questions?

Comment: @user3670333: Because a quick Google search for `declaring a variable in Java` would give you more than enough resources to answer your question. Your question "does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 1):

`i` hasn't been declared as an `int` value. Try using `int i = tGen();`.

On another note, you'll need to return some sort of `int` value in your `tortoiseMoves()` method, since it is a return method of the same type.